# Onclick - how to use function on different page that it calls?

Tags: javascript, onclick

So, my problem is that:

I've got function which show/hide some parts of text, and when I clicked a link 'show more', or sth like that (it's not important, couse I can write there anything) it show me this hidden content.

It changes 'display: none' to 'display: block', and looks like that:

```
<!--
function showOrHide(co) { 
var obiekt = document.getElementById(co); 
if (obiekt.style.display == 'block') { 
    obiekt.style.display = 'none'; 
} else { 
    obiekt.style.display = 'block'; 
} 
}
-->
```

And I need to put that opening link on other page.

```
<a onclick="location.href = 'page/#poco1';showOrHide('poco1'); return false;">Check</a>
```

I tried that, but it only take me to this site where I've got this and this other onclick function doesn't want to work.

On other pages this 'location.href' works, when I want to go to the other area of the page - when am calling something by 'name' attribute - but it's still on this same page :(

Can you help me?
I don't have any other ideas to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute javascript on remote page like this. You can use Messages in HTML5, or javascript in popup's page to show/hide poco1 when popup is loaded.

Comment: It's in Wordpress and that first function works - location.href is a function, right?

Comment: Yes, but you want the second instruction (showOrHide) to be executed in 'page/#poco1', right?

Comment: Try to open the page like this: `location.href = 'page?x=#poco1';`, then use JavaScript in page to execute, after loading is complete, a javascript method that will get value of parameter `X` and show/hide the div `X` (assuming you can modify "page").

Comment: I don't know javascript so well, so could you write me that function?
Am good only in fitting the code to my needs, not in writing it...